# Store a ratio value in command and then use it to recalculate a length?

Tags: calculations, lengths

I want to store a ratio value in a command, e.g. `\newcommand{\ratio}{0.7}`, and then use it in recalculating a length, e.g. `\setlength{\somelength}{\ratio*\width}`.

Using lengths to store the ratio doesn't seem to work as it requires a unit (but ratios are unitless). I've also tried using `calc` but I can't seem to get it to work.

How should I go about this?

**EDIT:**
Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\newcommand{\widthRatio}{0.7}
\newlength{\newWidth}
\setlength{\newWidth}{\widthRatio*\textwidth} % Doesn't compile

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If `\width` is a register like `\textwidth` then your code would work if you omit `*`

Comment: With code samples of your unsuccesful attempts, it would be better, and you would likely get a full answer instead of a one liner from @David.

Comment: @tohecz: There, minimal example added. =)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Cool, didn't know about that! Could you please add that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `\textwidth` is a dimen register if you omit the `*` it is already correct syntax.